# How to generate Sankey diagrams using Brightway2?

Tags: python, sankey-diagram, brightway

I know that we can get Sankey diagrams using activity-browser. Is there a way we can generate a sankey diagram for one of the ecoinvent activities using brightway2 functions and python?

I looked into brightway2 functions but couldn't find one that I can readily use for sankey diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, at least right now. The [activity-browser implementation](https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser/blob/master/activity_browser/ui/web/sankey_navigator.py) is licensed [LGPL](https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser/blob/master/LICENSE.txt), which isn't compatible with the Brightway license, so we can't just copy what they have done. There are also technical limitations, as an interactive graphic would need a server/client architecture for new calculations (e.g. changing the cutoff), or serializing a very large result dataset for use in something like plotly.

It would be amazing to have the community step up with a stand-along program; see also the ongoing [visualization contest](https://github.com/Depart-de-Sentier/visualization-contest-2022/).

Answer (score 0):

There is [polyviz](https://github.com/romainsacchi/polyviz) which generates next to a lot of other visualizations also sankey diagramms with [d3](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/sankey.html) and [sankertainpy](https://github.com/HaSchneider/sankertainpy) for generating sankey diagrams including visualization options of uncertainty with [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/). Both where outcomes of the mentioned visualization contest!